# Не понимаю пример Шилдта про фабрику класса

Tags: c#

недавно начал изучать С#. До этого с языками программирования дела не имел. Сейчас читаю про фабрику класса и Шилдт предоставляет пример:

```
using System;

class MyClass
{
int a, b; // private 

// Create a class factory for MyClass. 
public MyClass Factory(int i, int j)
{
    MyClass t = new MyClass();

    t.a = i;
    t.b = j;

    return t; // return an object 
}

public void Show()
{
    Console.WriteLine("a and b: " + a + " " + b);
}

}

 class MakeObjects
{
static void Main()
{
    MyClass ob = new MyClass();
    int i, j;

    // Generate objects using the factory. 
    for (i = 0, j = 10; i < 10; i++, j--)
    {
        MyClass anotherOb = ob.Factory(i, j); // make an object 
        anotherOb.Show();
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    }
    }
```

Возможно это очень тупой вопрос, но в этом коде мне не понятен отрывок:

```
public MyClass Factory(int i, int j)
```

Чем это является(методом или чем-либо ещe)?
Почему так странно объявлен этот отрывок кода? Меня смущает то, что здесь не указан возвращаемый тип. А также то, что здесь написано название класса в объявление метода.

Comment: Это паттерн Factory Method, но с очень странной реализацией. Здесь описан вариант получше https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/2.1.php -- https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/factory-method/csharp/example

Comment: обычный метод, никаких странностей. Вы бы пояснили что вас конкретно смущает.

Comment: Я думаю, что человека смущает, что создаётся пустой экземпляр класса, который умеет создавать экземпляры класса со смыслом (конкретными данными). Выглядит странно. В данном случае вместо конструктора вызывается этот метод.

Comment: @tym32167 Меня смущает то, что здесь не указан возвращаемый тип. А также то, что здесь написано название класса в объявление метода.

Comment: @Evp, 1[Модификатор доступа] 2[Возвращаемый тип] 3[Название метода] 4(Параметры). 1[public] 2[MyClass] 3[Factory] 4(int i, int j) - что здесь не так? Метод объявлен правильно. Я думал, вас смущает сам пример.

Comment: Спасибо) Я чуть чуть не понимал...

Comment: Метод у которого в качестве возвращаемого типа указан сам класс `MyClass` видимо сбил с толку. Здесь для возврата используется новый объект:  `MyClass t = new MyClass(); ... return t;`. Иногда объект возвращает ссылку на самого себя `return this;` и так устраиваются цепочные вызовы. Вы могли это видеть при использовании StringBuilder: `string s = new StringBuilder().Append("this").Append(' ').Append("is a ").Append("silly way to").AppendLine("append strings").ToString();`. Просто метод `Append` возвращает сам объект: `public StringBuilder Append(string s) { .... ; return this; }`.